# RNN vs Simple Neural Network

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

(I conceptually understand how RNN works. I have also used RNN/LSTM as well for some use cases)

To understand RNN and RNN-variant model's working deeply, I wanted to try out some experiment.

Obvious choice for this experiment was - Sequencing Problem.

**Experiment Objective :** 
When I will train a simple sequencing problem with NeuralNet it shouldn't perform well but when I train/tune on RNN it should perform reasonabaly well (given I have sufficient amount of data)

**Problem Simulation:**
I have generated 10,000 rows of sequences and each row looks like this:

- generate randomly some number "num_x" between 1-10k

  x1 = sin(num_x)

  x2 = sin(x1)

  x3 = sin(x1)

  x4 = sin(x1)

  x5 = sin(x1)

  **X for this row is = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]**

  **y for this row is:**
  y = sin(x6) .... so by training model, we need to predict this next number is sequence.

**So as we clearly see, each number in a sequence is a non-linear and it depends on earlier number in a sequence.**

So I thought this is definately a very good sequence problem and it should behave badly on simple NN and perform reasonablly well on RNN (after tuning)

But to my surprise, it performs very good NN without even fine tuning. 
And it performs very bad on RNN model (but we can forget this part for now)

I want to understand, why is it performing better on NN?

I used RMSE metric and ran it for 100 epcohs. RMSE is 2.5 without tuning
(For RNN, RMSE is 37K)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I thought this sequence is very simple task to learn for NN. So I made my sequences little complex.

```
  num_1 = math.sin(i) 
  num_2 = math.sin(num_1) 
  num_3 = math.sin(num_2) + math.cos(num_1) 
  num_4 = math.sin(num_3) + math.cos(num_2) + math.cos(num_1)
  num_5 = math.sin(num_4) + math.cos(num_3) + math.cos(num_2) + math.cos(num_1)

  x = [num_1, num_2,num_3, num_4,num_5]
  y_num = math.sin(num_5) + math.cos(num_4) + math.cos(num_3) + math.cos(num_2) + math.cos(num_1)
```

But NN is very smart and it learns this complex sequnece too.
So I asked about this to my scientist friend. I am quoting his answer here:

"First the sequences you are building are not complex ones. They are regular, bounded , deterministic ones and the functions you have chosen are periodic ones. Linear superposition of these periodic functions even when iteratively applied is likely to have short range order. Neural networks can learn non linear functions of arbitrary order. You are asking the network to map a 5 dimensional space to a 1 d space which most neural networks can do. 
"

So lesson learnt from this exercise is:

**NN models are capable of learning simple to semi complex low dimensional  sequencing problems. But it will be slower as compared to.
Hence we use them in NLP kind of high-dimensional and very complex problems.**